# Moment local time to utc conversion just giving local time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, utc

I'm trying to get a UTC time string in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format but when using moment it's just giving the local input time back, what am I doing wrong?

```
moment('2019-04-16 22:00:00:').utc()
```

This returns a moment object with the value of `2019-04-16 22:00:00`

Comment: Maybe this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/4/light/) I found by googling *"jsfiddle moment conversion"* might be of some help to you.

Comment: @NewToJS Not helpful, I'm trying to convert an already known local timestamp into UTC.

Comment: Converting a time/date from a string to .`utc()` will return the same as your input because it doesn't have anything to convert from. What are your expectation/use for this? Maybe knowing will help me understand your goal. Thank you.

Comment: I want to input a local timestamp in `2019-04-16 22:00:00` format and get out the UTC timestamp of that value.

Comment: @NewToJS Yes, that is what I"m looking for except I want to pass my own date into it, so for example the local timestamp of `2019-04-16 22:00:00` should return `2019-04-17 02:00:00`

Running `moment.utc('2019-04-16').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');` Just gives me `2019-04-16 00:00:00` instead of my expected `2019-04-16 02:00:00`

Comment: Okay maybe I am closer to what you are looking for with this one? [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/zp6842gq/)

Comment: @NewToJS Yup, that is what I want thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example which converts local time to UTC. Check it out

```js
var local = moment.utc().local().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log(local, "- local");
var date = moment(local).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log(date, "- local now in UTC");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment-timezone` library, you can input any timezone want to convert to UTC.

```
var input = "2019-04-16 22:00:00"
var format   = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss";
var yourzone  = "Asia/Seoul";

var yourtime = moment.tz(input, format, yourzone);

// convert to utc
yourtime.utc();

// format output
var result = yourtime.format(format) 
console.log(result)
```

```js
var input = "2019-04-16 22:00:00"
var format   = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss";
var yourzone  = "Asia/Seoul";

var yourtime = moment.tz(input, format, yourzone);

// convert to utc
yourtime.utc();

// format output
var result = yourtime.format(format) 
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
<p id="london"></p>
```